# Elasticsearch: Which indices to backup?

Tags: elasticsearch, snapshot

I want to backup my elasticsearch data and it's unclear to me what's the purpose of all the indices and which ones I need to backup.

When I asked elasticsearch to give me a list of indices I received an awful long list.

My idea is to just backup our "scans-staging" index, but I'm "overwhelmed" by the amount of indices shown to me.

What's their purpose? Would I need to backup anything else besides my "scans-staging" index in order to restore our valuable data?

As far as I know, the metricbeat* and logstash indices are not really required, but what are all these indices starting with a dot?

```
health status index                              pri rep docs.count
yellow open   metricbeat-7.2.0-2019.07.21-000001   1   1   20174772
green  open   .monitoring-logstash-7-2019.08.23    1   0     138192
yellow open   scans-staging                        1   1     135406
green  open   .security-7                          1   0         39
green  open   .monitoring-kibana-7-2019.08.27      1   0       8639
green  open   .reporting-2019.07.28                1   0          3
green  open   .monitoring-es-7-2019.08.24          1   0     286270
green  open   .monitoring-logstash-7-2019.08.22    1   0     138192
green  open   .monitoring-kibana-7-2019.08.24      1   0       8639
green  open   .monitoring-logstash-7-2019.08.28    1   0         48
green  open   .monitoring-logstash-7-2019.08.27    1   0     138192
green  open   .monitoring-kibana-7-2019.08.22      1   0       8639
yellow open   logstash                             1   1   30796050
green  open   .monitoring-kibana-7-2019.08.23      1   0       8639
green  open   .monitoring-kibana-7-2019.08.25      1   0       8640
green  open   .monitoring-logstash-7-2019.08.24    1   0     138200
green  open   .monitoring-es-7-2019.08.23          1   0     286301
green  open   .monitoring-es-7-2019.08.27          1   0     286299
green  open   .reporting-2019.07.21                1   0          2
green  open   .kibana_1                            1   0        644
green  open   .monitoring-es-7-2019.08.28          1   0        178
green  open   .monitoring-logstash-7-2019.08.26    1   0     138200
green  open   .monitoring-es-7-2019.08.25          1   0     286301
green  open   .monitoring-es-7-2019.08.22          1   0     286299
yellow open   metricbeat-7.2.0-2019.08.20-000002   1   1    5181869
green  open   .monitoring-logstash-7-2019.08.25    1   0     138192
green  open   .monitoring-kibana-7-2019.08.26      1   0       8639
green  open   .monitoring-kibana-7-2019.08.28      1   0          3
green  open   .monitoring-es-7-2019.08.26          1   0     286270
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.monitoring include monitoring information of components. they are system indices.  for example .monitoring-es-7 have information about indices stats, index rate, search rate, cluster stats, and ETC. 
you don't need backup these indices. actually, you don't need backup indices that begin with dot.

Comment: I would still backup the `.security-7` one, though, if you are using security.